# select first child with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select first child of ul and then remove it and then append it in the end of that ul but unfortunately i can not selet first child.

Here is code

```
current = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

    width=951;

    var totalSlides=$(".slider ul li").length;
    $(".slider ul").removeAttr('width');
    $(".slider ul").attr('width',width*totalSlides);

    $('#next img').click(function(){
        current -= width;
        $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "slow");
        $(".slider ul").append($(".slider ul:first-child"));
        //$('.slider ul:firstChild').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: OT: I guess no one told you that you could chain jQuery function calls. Most functions return the original selector, so you can write `$('.slider ul').animate(...).append(...);`

Comment: Actually, you should just read the entire [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/), as you don't need to remove the width before setting the width, and either case you should use the `width` function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to [`.remove()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [`.detach()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) a node to append it somewhere else. You can do it by just invoking [`.append()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.appendTo()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) respectively [`.after()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [`.insertAfter`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/). For instance:

```
$('ul li:first').insertAfter('ul li:last');
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/KFk4P/

Comment: Is this a subtle cry for *help*? ;o)

Answer (score 15):

The first child of the `ul` can be selected:

```
$('ul > :first-child');
```

or:

```
$('ul').children().eq(0);
```

or:

```
$('ul li:first');
```

There are, probably, many other ways though.

Answer (score 10):

Any of these will work:

- `$('ul > li:first')`
- `$('ul > li:first-child')`
- `$('ul > li:eq(0)')`
- `$('ul > li:nth-child(1)')`
- `$('ul > li').eq(0)`
- `$('ul > li').first()`
- `$('ul > li')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`ul:first-child` does not select the first child of `ul`, it selects the ul which is the first child *itself*. Use `li:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

first, make a class for every first span, like so:

```
<li><span class = "the_span">a1</span><span>b1</<span></li>
<li><span class = "the_span">a2</span><span>b2</<span></li>
<li><span class = "the_span">a3</span><span>b3</span></li>`
```

The in the Javascript, you write:

```
var spanEl = document.getElementsByClassName("the_span");
```

There you go!